# Classes can only mix in mixins and classes, The argument type '_CountdownPageState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider' problem

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know how this errors apperas. Anyone can help me figure out the solution?

The error is Classes can only mix in mixins and classes  using TickerProviderStateMixin

and the second is The argument type '_CountdownPageState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider'  using vsync: this

The countdown page

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_first/Screens/profile.dart';
import '../round-button.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ringtone_player/flutter_ringtone_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'details.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class CountdownPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CountdownPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CountdownPageState createState() => _CountdownPageState();
}

class _CountdownPageState extends State<CountdownPage>
  with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  Timer? timer;
  int pausedTimer = 0;
  bool isPause = false;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  final DatabaseReference timerRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Users/FirstUser/Sensor1/counttime');
  int timerValue = 0;
  String get countText {
    Duration count = controller.duration! * controller.value;
    return controller.isDismissed
        ? '${controller.duration!.inHours}:${(controller.duration!.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'
        : '${count.inHours}:${(count.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  double progress = 1.0;
  

  void notify() {
    if (countText == '0:00:00') {
      FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification();
      
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timerRef.set(timerValue);
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 60),
    );
    controller.addListener(() {
      notify();
      if (controller.isAnimating) {
        setState(() {
          progress = controller.value;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          progress = 1.0;
          isPlaying = false;
          checkTimerCompletion(); // Check if the timer has completed
        });
      }
    });
  }
  
@override
void dispose() {
  controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}



void startTimer() {
  timer?.cancel(); // Cancel the previous timer if it exists
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) {
    // Update the timer value
    if (isPlaying == true) {
      setState(() {
        timerValue -= 1;
      });
    }
    timerRef.set(timerValue);
    if (timerValue <= 0) {
      restTimer();
      controller.reset();
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = false;
      });
    }
  });
}


void stopTimer() {
  timer?.cancel(); // Cancel the timer if it's not null
  if(isPause){
  setState(() {
    pausedTimer = timerValue;
  });
  timerRef.set(pausedTimer);
  }
}

void restTimer() {
  timer?.cancel(); // Cancel the timer if it's not null
  setState(() {
    timerValue = 0;
    controller.reset();
  });
  timerRef.set(timerValue);
}

void checkTimerCompletion() {
  if (countText == '0:00:00') {
    restTimer();
    controller.reset();
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = false;
    });
  }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Timer Page'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0C9869),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff5fbff),
        body: 
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [ 
           Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
           SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    value: progress,
                    strokeWidth: 6,
                  ),
           ),
                     GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (controller.isDismissed) {
                      if(!isPlaying){
                      showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => Container(
                          height: 300,
                          child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                            initialTimerDuration: controller.duration!,
                            onTimerDurationChanged: (time) {
                                setState(() {
                                controller.duration = time;
                                timerValue = time.inSeconds;
                                timerRef.set(timerValue);
                                if(!isPause){
                                  stopTimer();
                                }
                                else {
                                  startTimer();
                                  timerRef.set(pausedTimer);
                                }
                              });  
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    }
                  },
                         child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: controller,
                    builder: (context, child) => Text(
                      countText,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 60,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                          ],
           
          ),
                     Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (controller.isAnimating) {
                      controller.stop();
                      stopTimer();
                      setState(() {
                        isPlaying = false;
                      });
                    } else {
                      startTimer();
                      isPlaying = false;
                      controller.reverse(
                      from: controller.value == 0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);
                      setState(() {
                        isPlaying = true;
                        isPause = false;

                      });
                     }
                  },
                  child: RoundButton( 
                    icon: isPlaying == true ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    restTimer();
                    setState(() {
                      isPlaying = false;
                      isPause = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: RoundButton(
                    icon: Icons.stop,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ), 
          
      ],
      ),
     
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 5,
      ),
      height: 60,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(80),
          topRight: Radius.circular(80),
        ),
        color: Color(0xFF0C9869),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(offset: Offset(0,-10),
          blurRadius: 35,
          color:Color(0xFF0C9869).withOpacity(0.38) ),
          
        ]
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton(onPressed: (){
             Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => home(user: user!,)),
                                );
          }, 
          icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/home4.svg", height: 30),
          ),
            SizedBox(width: 60,),
          IconButton(onPressed: (){
             Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => details()),
                                  );
          }, 
          icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/plant8.svg", height:60,),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 60,),
           IconButton(onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => profile()),
                                );
           }, 
          icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/profile2.svg", height: 30),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

I will be very greatful for anyone help me becasue after 2 days i have a presentation and this code is needed for my senior project presentation

1. Uninstall the visual studio code -> nothing happened
2. Search in google and that's without any benifits

Comment: try running flutter clean and remove pubspec.lock then flutter pub get